# Can a player lose their last army?

Tags: tiny-epic-kingdoms

I know that a a region with a player's last army cannot be invaded.

However, I played a solo game and the dummy player kept starting wars with their last army. I consistently won those wars and played so that they retreat to the nearest empty region, whilst paying the relevant food cost.

My question is, **was I playing this correctly and a player can never lose their last army (even if they suicidally throw it away)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [core rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/101411/official-rules-tiny-epic-kingdoms):

> You may never enter a region occupied by an opposing player’s last meeple
>   (i.e., the only meeple they have in play), **nor may you use your last meeple to
>   enter a region occupied by an opponent.**

From the [solo rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/121331/official-rule-book-tiny-epic-kingdoms-heroes-call):

> If [the meeple] cannot move in the selected direction, continue clockwise until you find a region it can move into.

and

> The dummy player may always collect resources if they are unable to fulfill the action, even if they are the active player.

So suicidally throwing away your last army is illegal for both real players and the dummy, and the dummy will choose a different place to move instead (or collect resources if there are no legal moves).